# How to draw chain of Circle with dynamic text inside in asp.net through vb.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to draw circles with text inside, where the text comes dynamically from database. if i a enters "A" in the textbox and hit a button the circles with text should appear, where i will send the "A" to the db and fetch other character like " H", "X", "C", "L".... and draws like the image i attached, all the text should be clickable if i click "H" it should go the db and bring some characters, how to do this in asp.net with vb.net coding

[image]

Comment: can you embed image ? can't see it

Comment: i am able to see, please check now